# How to start kafka on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

My aim is to start a kafka topic with multiple partitions on kubernetes.
To do that I deploy the following .yml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: kafka

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-kafka
  namespace: kafka
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-kafka
spec:
  containers:
    - name: zookeeper
      image: zookeeper
      env:
      - name: ZOO_MY_ID
        value: "1"


    - name: kafka
      image: wurstmeister/kafka
      env:
      - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME
        value: "kubernetes-cluster.nt"
      - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT
        value: 30001
      - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
        value: "localhost:2181"
      - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
        value: "1"
      - name: KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS
        value: write:20:1

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-kafka
  namespace: kafka
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-kafka
  ports:
  - name: zk-client
    port: 2181
    protocol: TCP
  - name: zk-follower
    port: 2888
    protocol: TCP
  - name: zk-election
    port: 3888
    protocol: TCP
  - name: zk-admin
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  - name: kafka-client
    port: 9092
    nodePort: 30001
    protocol: TCP
```

I expect this code to create a `kafka` server on `kubernetes`, whose `write` topic  can be accessible via `host:port = kubernetes-cluster.nt:30001`

However, although kubernetes service and pod are started (`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` and `kubectl get services --all-namespaces` commands list entries with the name kubernetes-kafka), the kafka topic is not created:

```
kafkacat -b kubernetes-cluster.nt:30001 -L
```

which should list all topics returns that 0 topics are created:

```
Metadata for all topics (from broker 1: kubernetes-cluster.nt:30001/1):
 1 brokers:
   broker 1 at kubernetes-cluster.nt:30001
 0 topics:
```

**What am I doing wrong**?

Comment: Well, your advertised port is not 30003. Also, is the pod actually starting? You can't set Zookeeper to be localhost if it's in another pod

Comment: @cricket_007 There was a typo, I edited the post. The topics still don't start, the pod I assume has started, if kafkacat returns some info about the broker?

Comment: I would check the logs of the actual kafka service rather than rely on kafkacat. A proper Zookeeper connection is needed to create topics.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that Kafka external port and k8s service nodePort are consistent, Other services call k8s-service:nodeport. write this [config_kafka_in_kubernetes](https://bbotte.github.io/virtualization/config_kafka_in_kubernetes), hope to help U !

Answer (score 0):

I would use a operator to run Kafka in Kubernetes.
I would recommend [Strimzi kafka operator](https://strimzi.io/docs/overview/latest/).